# Redirect to another domain but keep rest of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have two domains in may server, **a.com** which is my main domain and **a.fr** which is my redirect domain.

I like when the user enter `http://a.fr/dynamicpath/` automatically going to `http://a.com/dynamicpath/`, is it possible to accomplish this through `htaccess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://a.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```